# Why were there pictures of P.T.'s family in the bar?

Tags: the-greatest-showman

In The Greatest Showman, during the "From Now On" scene, P.T. looks at pictures of his family that are on the wall of the bar. We know this is a public bar because he has Philip pay for their drinks earlier in the movie. Why were there pictures of his family in the bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar has several pictures of P.T. and his accomplishments on the wall. Since he's (in)famous, and frequents there, the pictures may be for publicity (several restaurants take pictures when they have celebrities visit and hang the images on the walls), or be featuring local news and a prominent figure in the community.